# Eliminating Visited Slides from Powerpoint Slide Summary

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I've been using Powerpoint's Slide Zoom feature to make a really good-looking quiz show template for a thing I'm running.

Because slides can be viewed in any order, contestants can select categories/questions in whatever order they want, be brought to the slide for said question, complete the question, then return to the 'home' slide.

The problem is I would like slides that have already been visited to disappear, be blanked out, or otherwise be visually distinct from ones that haven't. I can get an animation to hide or vanish a slide, but if I...

- Zoom Slide 01
- Complete Slide 01
- Return to Home Slide
- Use animation to remove Slide 01's preview (or otherwise hide it)
- Zoom Slide 02
- Complete Slide 02
- Return to Home Slide

...The animation which removed or hid Slide 01 has been undone.

Now, there is one way to zoom then return without undoing animations, which is 'previous slide'-ing my way out of the zoom instead of waiting for the zoom to return to the home slide. The problem with this is it visually undoes any animations on the question slides themselves, which looks a little gross.

**In short**, I want to know how to structure my Powerpoint Presentation so that I can:

- Visit several slides with questions in any order
- Be able to return to the slide which links to the rest upon completion of a question
- Have visited slides be distinct from those visited (visually or functionally)

Any ideas?

[Link to my current presentation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dpm9wfc61ofoyqx/Quiz%20Test.pptx?dl=0).

Answer (score 1):

After much more research, I found you can complete this using the method from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFrPQpmAMpE).

In short, you need a small clickable button which uses an 'Action' on-click to return to your home slide, which will preserve previous animations. This means after each round you can select a hidden button to hide the used category, then upon returning to it later it will still be hidden. You can also (by placing multiple separate summary zooms in a single slide) make it so that clicking the summary zoom will change the colour of/vanish a given summary slide, achieving the same effect.

**Note:** You'll need to copy and paste summary slides in order to get multiple on a single slide. It seems that making a new one automatically puts it on a new slide.